# Obejctive-c: UIImageView 22x22 is grainy

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I would like to use an image as a checkmark in my `UITableViewCell`.
This image is 512 × 512.

I created a large `UIImageView` 22 x 22, and inserted this image.

The result is shown below. The checkmark looks very grainy, even though the image quality is high. Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Fixed a few formatting issues, and added a new tag.

Answer (score 0):

Downscaling can also produce visual artifacts. It also unnecessarily uses up processing power if it’s done at runtime.

I think it would be better to downscale the asset to 22x22 (+ Retina dimensions of course) in your favorite graphics editor and use this already downscaled asset.

Comment: is the same, I've downloaded the same image 22x22 but nothing has changed..is grainy :(

Comment: Please show how you set the image and the image itself then.